# Node.js communcation with DynamoDB- JSON

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I try to get data from DynamoDB which userLimit is between lower and higher value. I send lower value to my code with JSON. My Node.js code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();


exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var low=event.ke1;

  var params = {
    TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
    ProjectionExpression: "userLimit, description",  //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
    FilterExpression: "userLimit between :lower and :higher",
    // ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    //     "#yr": "year",
    // },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":lower": {"N": "low"},
        ":higher": {"N": "50"}
    }
};

  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
           console.log(
                record.description.S + "");
        });
        context.succeed(data.Items);
    // context.done(null,{"Result": "Operation succeeded."});
      //res.send(data.name);
      }
   // return next();
  });
};
```

I get an error:

```
[ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: low for key :lower]
  message: 'ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: low for key :lower',
```

If I change  `":lower": {"N": "low"},` to  `":lower": {"N": low},` error is:

```
{ [ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes for key :lower]
  message: 'ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes for key :lower',
```

My JSON data is:

```
{
  "key1": "1"
}
```

How to set that lower value with the value from the key1?

EDIT:

There was mistake in:

```
 var low=event.ke1;
```

Shuld be

`var low=event.key1;`

EDIT 2:

Another error occured when I was running that code:

```
 var params = {
    TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
    ProjectionExpression: "userLimit, description, type",  //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
    KeyConditionExpression: "type = :tempType",
    // ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    //     "#yr": "year",
    // },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tempType": {"S": "Party"}
    }
};
```

Error:

```
{ [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params]
  message: 'Unexpected key \'KeyConditionExpression\' found in params',
```

EDIT 3:

My current code is:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB(); 


exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var low=event.key1;

  var params = {
    TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
    ProjectionExpression: "ID, userLimit, description, #tp",  //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
    KeyConditionExpression: "#tp = :tempType",
     ExpressionAttributeNames: {
         "#tp": "type",
     },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tempType": {"S": "Party"}
    }
};

  db.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
           console.log(
                record.description.S + "");
        });
        context.succeed(data.Items);
    // context.done(null,{"Result": "Operation succeeded."});
      //res.send(data.name);
      }
   // return next();
  });
};
```

But I get an error:

```
{ [ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: ID]
  message: 'Query condition missed key schema element: ID',
```

Answer (score 2):

"KeyConditionExpression" is not applicable for a `scan` operation.

You need to change your operation to query, if the attribute is an idexed field or use `FilterExpression` if it has to be a scan operation.

Comment: The point is that i want to get that lower value via JSON.
To be more clear I want Lower = event.ke1

Comment: lower value via json? Are you expecting to dynamically substitute the lowest value as in sub-query on an  sql DB?

Comment: updated my answer. Remove the json issue description from the question.

Comment: It worked but now I got another error. Check my question

Comment: the db seems to have a primary key/rangekey, which u are not including in the query. Queries on dynamodb always needs these attriibutes or else you will need to use scan

Comment: My primary key is ID and i icluded it here:  ProjectionExpression: "ID, userLimit, description, #tp". Should i do it somewhere else?

Comment: It should be in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your hashkey and index you could use:

DynamoDB query:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'table_name',
    KeyConditions: { // indexed attributes to query
                     // must include the hash key value of the table or index 
                     // with 'EQ' operator
        attribute_name: {
            ComparisonOperator: 'EQ', // (EQ | NE | IN | LE | LT | GE | GT | BETWEEN | 
                                      //  NOT_NULL | NULL | CONTAINS | NOT_CONTAINS | BEGINS_WITH)
            AttributeValueList: [ { S: 'STRING_VALUE' }, ],
        },
        // more key conditions ...
    }
};
dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

or DynamoDB scan:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'table_name',
    Limit: 0, // optional (limit the number of items to evaluate)
    ScanFilter: { // optional (map of attribute name to Condition)

        attribute_name: {
            ComparisonOperator: 'EQ', // (EQ | NE | IN | LE | LT | GE | GT | BETWEEN | 
                                      //  NOT_NULL | NULL | CONTAINS | NOT_CONTAINS | BEGINS_WITH)
            AttributeValueList: [ { S: 'STRING_VALUE' }, ],
        },
        // more conditions ...
    }
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```